# I want to access particular array from an object in react

Tags: reactjs

`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Star } from 'react-feather'
import { useLocation, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function MovieDetail() {

```
const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState([]);
const [topCast, setTopCast] = useState([]);

const location = useLocation()
const state = location.state;


const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJmYWFiNThjYTQ2NjQ4YzRkOTY2YWFkM2Q5YWYyMzg2ZCIsInN1YiI6IjY1MjNmNTNjNzQ1MDdkMDBlMjEzYWYxOSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.o0jIrBzscUCOP9mAERuXait3-UD8sDADG4jdTLteDa0'
    }
};

const MovieDetail = async () => {
    let movie;
    let CastDetails
    if (state.movieid) {
        try {
            movie = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${state.movieid}?language=en-US`, options);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error getting movieDetails: ', err);
        }

        if (movieDetails) {
            const parsedData = await movie.json();
            setMovieDetails(parsedData);
        }

        try {
            CastDetails = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${state.movieid}/credits`, options);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error getting CastDetails: ', err);
        }

        if (CastDetails) {
            const CastData = await CastDetails.json();
            const topcastSliced = CastData.cast;
            setTopCast(topcastSliced.slice(0, 5));
        }
    }
}
console.log(movieDetails)

useEffect(() => {
    MovieDetail()
},[])

return (
    <>
        <section className="Main-Header-Div">

            <>
                <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movieDetails.poster_path}`} key={movieDetails.id} className="MainPoster" />
                <div className='Header-Movie-Details'>
                    <h2 className="MovieTitle">{movieDetails.title}</h2>
                    <h2 className='text-xl mt-2'><b>{movieDetails.tagline}</b></h2>
                    <div className='MovieRating'>
                        <div className='mx-8'>
                            <p> <Star color='gold' /> </p> <b><p className='m-4'> {movieDetails.vote_average} / 10 </p></b>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p><b>{movieDetails.runtime} Mins / {movieDetails.release_date} / {movieDetails.original_language}</b></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            //i want to add genres here
                    </div>
                    <h2 className='text-xl underline'><b>Overview </b></h2>
                    <h1 className='MovieOverView text-left'>{movieDetails.overview}</h1>

                    <p className='font-black font-semibold text-2xl mt-4'><b>Top Cast</b></p>

                    
                </div>

            </>
        </section>


    </>
)
```

}`

i want to add genres or want to loop genres array in a div. can anyone please help me get the data and print the genres there. whole object is in movieDetails.

[image]